# how can i get first, second and third TD values using php and dom

Tags: php, dom

i have a table such this:

```
<tr>
    <td><font color="#000066">ADANA</font></td>
    <td><font color="#000066">SEYHAN</font></td>    
    <td><font color="#000066">ZÜBEYDE HANIM ANAOKULU</font></td>    
    <td><font color="#000066">KURTULUŞ MAH.64011 SOK. NO:1</font></td>    
    <td><font color="#000066">(322) 453 10 60</font></td>    
    <td><font color="#000066">(322) 459 19 77</font></td> 
</tr>
```

And I want to get td's content. But I could not manage it.

```
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->validateOnParse = true;
    $xml->loadHTML($data);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
    $table =$xpath->query("//*[@id='dgKurumListesi']")->item(0);

    $rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr");

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cells = $row -> getElementsByTagName('td',0);
    foreach ($cells as $cell) {
        echo $cell->nodeValue; //il ismi
    }

}
```

i want like this: `$value['firsttd'] , $value['secondtd'], $value['thirdtd']`

Comment: So what's the result?

Comment: result is= ADANASEYHANZÜBEYDE HANIM ANAOKULUKURTULUŞ MAH.64011 SOK. NO:1(322) 453 10 60(322) 459 19 77"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `for` to limit the result to only the first 3 items on the `td`:

```
$value = array();
$table = $xpath->query("//*[@id='dgKurumListesi']")->item(0);
$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr");
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    // Keep in mind that the elements index start at 0
    // so we want 0, 1, 2 to get the first 3.
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
    {
        if (is_object($cells->item($i)))
            $value[] = $cells->item($i)->nodeValue;
    }
}
print_r($value);
```

**[Live DEMO.](https://eval.in/40196)**

And you can output the resulting `$value` with:

```
foreach ($value as $item)
{
    echo $item, "<br />\n";
}
```

Based on your comment, you could use a multidimensional array like this:

```
for ($r = 0; $r < $rows->length; $r++)
{
    if (!is_object($rows->item($r)))
        continue;

    $cells = $rows->item($r)->getElementsByTagName('td');
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
    {
        if (is_object($cells->item($i)))
            $value[$r][$i] = $cells->item($i)->nodeValue;
    }
}

foreach ($value as $item)
{
    echo $item[0], ',', $item[1], ',', $item[2], "\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you its good. can i use this like this: $item[0], item[1], item[2] ?

Comment: @user1363426 you can use as `$value[0]` or you can change it to $item instead so you can use `$item[0]`. Kindly mark this answer as the right answer if it solves your problem, [**see how here.**](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: i have 50000 tr like this and i want get all values and save my databese in  different field. caps: http://i.imgur.com/fyiNwtf.png . sorry for my broken english.

Comment: @user1363426 you can use a multidimensional array see update on my answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to do with simplexml.

```
$dom = simplexml_load_string($data);
$rows = $dom->xpath('/tr/td/font');
$value = array(
    'firsttd'  => (string)$rows[0],
    'secondtd' => (string)$rows[1],
    'thirdtd'  => (string)$rows[2],
);
```