# How to get a specific cell value from a table element existing in a PHP array. Is this possible?

Tags: php, arrays

Guys, I have this piece of code:

```
<?php 

$url = 'https://www.kitco.com/gold-price-today-europe/';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div class="table-price--body-table--overview-detail">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );
echo $second_step[0];
//print_r ($second_step);

?>
```

The output of this code if I run it on my browser via loading the corresponding PHP file is the following:

[image]

Now, my question is how can I get the value from the table's cell marked in the yellow frame and place it in another PHP variable to continue working with my code?

Is this possible somehow?

Thanks in advance, George.

Comment: The answer is: "Yes, it is possible", But what have you tried to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Looks like you need to dig a little deeper, maybe use DOMDocument

Comment: Hello Luuk. Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I have been stuck on how to continue on this. I searched the web for some workarounds and similar questions, but I did not find anything that could solve my hands. Maybe, I was not able to approach my case properly. I would appreciate it if you could send me any links that could help me on this. Thanks again.

Comment: I think you'd definitely benefit from using an HTML parser. When you inspect that output, do these cells have an id you could utilize to pinpoint your desired value?

Comment: @El_Vanja unfortunately no. The rows and columns when I inspect them have no ids or classes. This is a good point of yours and this is why at the same time I found a big difficulty in this task.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you. I would totally make my research on this.

Comment: A parser is definitely the way to go then, as you would have to locate the element by its content ("Gold price per gram") and then find its sibling. Simple HTML DOM Parser has the functionalities you need (find [by content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060170/php-simple-html-dom-parser-how-to-get-the-element-which-has-certain-content) and [find sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732530/how-to-use-simple-html-dom-to-get-an-adjacent-sibling-element)). Not saying you should definitely use this library, but it should give you a general idea what to look for.

Comment: @El_Vanja these posts you attached seem really helpful. Let me try them and I will get back with my update. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: @El_Vanja I finally made this. Please, take a look at my answer below. Thank you all for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys, I finally made it with the following code. Of course, a piece of code was taken from the correct answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004204/how-can-i-get-first-second-and-third-td-values-using-php-and-dom)

```
<?php 

$url = 'https://www.kitco.com/gold-price-today-europe/';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div class="table-price--body-table--overview-detail">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );
//echo $second_step[0];
//print_r ($second_step);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($second_step[0]);
echo $doc->saveHTML();

$rows = $doc->getElementsByTagName("tr");
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    // Keep in mind that the elements index start at 0
    // so we want 0, 1, 2 to get the first 3.
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        if (is_object($cells->item($i))) {
            $value[] = $cells->item($i)->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}

//print_r($value);
$Gold_Price_Per_Gram = $value[4];
echo '<h2>Gold Price: <b>'.$Gold_Price_Per_Gram.'</b> </h2>';
```

I am also attaching here the new output on my browser:

[image]